# How to use gmail attachment preview for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gmail, gmail-api

Building a javascript browser plugin for Chrome which calls for the functionality of being able to select an attachment from a list and have the file open in Gmail's attachment preview (the large document preview against dark background that gives users options to download, share to Drive, etc).  Is there any way to access Gmail's attachment preview either through Gmail API or gmail.js?

Comment: I would think that you would need to code it yourself